# Eenhancing database tasks in Rails 5.0.1 / PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

We are enhancing `db:create` and `db:test:purge` tasks with a custom task to create a schema and enable `postgis`, `uuid-ossp` and `hstore` extensions as follows.

```
# lib/tasks/db_enhancements.rake
#
namespace :db do
  desc 'create shared_extensions Schema'
  task :extensions => :environment  do
    # Create Schema
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute 'CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS shared_extensions;'
    # Enable Hstore
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute 'CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS HSTORE SCHEMA shared_extensions;'
    # Enable UUID-OSSP
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute 'CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp" SCHEMA shared_extensions;'
    # Enable Postgis
    # Drop the postgis extension first
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute 'DROP EXTENSION "postgis"';
    # Create postgis in shared_extensions
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute 'CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "postgis" SCHEMA shared_extensions;'
  end
end

Rake::Task["db:create"].enhance do
  Rake::Task["db:extensions"].invoke
end

Rake::Task["db:test:purge"].enhance do
  Rake::Task["db:extensions"].invoke
end
```

The above task worked fine in Rails 4.2.5

rails `db:create` task should invoke the custom task, which in turn should create a `shared_extensions` schema and enable the extensions as shown below.

```
test_application_test=# \dx
                                         List of installed extensions
   Name    | Version |      Schema       |                             Description
-----------+---------+-------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------
 hstore    | 1.3     | shared_extensions | data type for storing sets of (key, value) pairs
 plpgsql   | 1.0     | pg_catalog        | PL/pgSQL procedural language
 postgis   | 2.2.1   | shared_extensions | PostGIS geometry, geography, and raster spatial types and functions
 uuid-ossp | 1.0     | shared_extensions | generate universally unique identifiers (UUIDs)
```

In Rails 5.0.1 ----

When `rails db:create` is run the `db:extensions` task creates the `shared_extensions` schema in development database, but not in the test database. On the other hand, if `rails db:create RAILS_ENV=test` is run before running `rails db:create`, `shared_extensions` schema is created for test database.

As noted above, the custom task worked fine in Rails 4.2.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems `rails db:create` is working as it should be. I had created a issue on GitHub rails/rails issues. [@rafaelfranca](https://github.com/rafaelfranca) clarified that in Rails 4.2 `db:test:purge` was called in `db:create` and not in Rails 5.0.

For now, Here is the workaround on command line.

`bin/rails db:environment:set RAILS_ENV=development
bin/rails db:drop
bin/rails db:create RAILS_ENV=test
bin/rails db:create
bin/rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
bin/rails db:migrate`